# Problem during Upgrade from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 Beta

Tags: 15.10, dpkg, do-release-upgrade, 16.04

I was upgrading my machine from Ubuntu 15.10 to Beta 16.04. At the end of the upgrade the following popped up:
    **"dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."**
    Your system might be in unusable state

Now it needs a restart but I am afraid that it wont wake up in stable working state from it shuts down to restart.

I ran     dpkg --reconfigure -a and    sudo apt-get install -f.
Is there anything else that anyone can suggest that can help me.
plus my software sources isn't opening.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason, the upgrade was interrupted. So some packages are upgraded while some are not. Hence your system is in a unstable state. You can resume your upgrade by running `dpkg --reconfigure -a`. If the upgrade finished successfully, it's perfectly fine to reboot.

But if the upgrade was interrupted again, there is a fair chance that the system may not reboot properly. In that case you will have to find out what is causing the issue, fix it, restart the upgrade again (`dpkg --reconfigure -a`) and let it finish before rebooting.

This is all I can tell you with the information you have given.

Comment: I did, but its all a giant mess not. So repos are of wily other of xenial. edited source.list and multiple duplicate repos.
Downloading ISO for fresh installation, its not worth the time fixing and editing files to make it stable.

Comment: I have the same problem and to solve this I run the above command as you say here  **sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a** , but there shows error agian .....dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !